# Optional in Java 8 return null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, option-type

I have the next code:

```
Optional<Account> account = accountClient.findTransactionByCriteria(customerId,accountId);
```

I throw a test and account return null, the accountClient is a mock in the test, so in the next code>

```
if (account.isPresent())
```

The method fail, How can avoid this problem?

Comment: For your test scenario, are you saying that `account` is null (i.e., `account == null`) or non-null?

Comment: I solved the problem :) in the test with mockito add Optional.isEmpty(), was easy

Comment: @nole Interesting, I didn't know JDK 8 `Optional` had an `isEmpty()` method. Perhaps you're using some other kind of `Optional`.

Comment: if `accountClient` is a mock, why dont you specify it to return `when(accountClient.findTransactionByCriteria(customerId,accountId)).thenReturn(Optional.of(someDummyAccount))`